# Перенос строк (мультистрочность) в JTable

Tags: java, swing

Помогите допилить CellRenderer для нормального автоматического переноса строк.
Сейчас при изменении размеров столбца/смены высоты ячейки вся таблица начинает сильно дёргаться (как я понимаю идёт авто-подсчёт высоты). Иногда вообще входит в зависание - т.е. туда-обратно дёргаются. Какие есть выходы из этой ситуации?

```
public class NotesTableCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
    public NotesTableCellRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(false);
        setOpaque(true);
    }
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),
            getPreferredSize().height);
    if (table.getRowHeight(row) != getPreferredSize().height) {  
            table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);  
        }
```

UPD: Код исправлен на верный

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что вывод содержимого ячейки был в конце метода. Перенёс его в начало

```
setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
```

Comment: подскажите, как потом применить этот код к таблице ? Можете привести пример ?

Comment: Уже совсем ничего не помню из Java. Попробуйте поискать примеры по getTableCellRendererComponent